# How to disable HTML Encoding for an entire Razor view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

We are using Razor outside of the typical MVC flow.  Our Razor views are called from within an XSL transform via a C# extension.  The output of the Razor view is returned to the xsl transform as a string.  In some cases we capture the result of a Razor view into an xsl variable and then pass that back out to our Model to be consumed as data in another Razor view.  When this happens we end up with the first view being double encoded, once by Razor, the second time via the xsl transform.  We need to be able to run Razor without having it encode the output.

Is this possible?  How would we go about it?

Comment: Not the complete answer, but you can use @(new HtmlString(Model.Something)) or @Html.Raw(Model.Something) to bypass the encoding.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm comfortable with using the encoding features available within the view.  In this case I'm returning the output of the view engine to another process and need to prevent the encoding performed by the engine on the entire view.  Its not just a matter of embedding some encoded data in the view.  I understand this is not a standard implementation.  In our case, we have a legacy system with a lot of backwards compatibility constraints that we are trying to modernize.  If successful, using Razor this way will allow us to migrate to MVC over a year or two.  Thanks for the input though.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since you want to disable encoding in your entire view, your best bet would be to create your own view base class inheriting from `WebPageBase` (and then your views should use `@inherits` to specify your new type) and override the `Write(object value)` method so that it calls `WriteLiteral()` instead. That way the output will not be encoded.

Comment: Thanks marcind - I was hoping you would chime in.  I'll give it a go.

Answer (score 5):

Further the the [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4661656/33969) you would achieve this like so:

```
public abstract class TextBasedViewPage : System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage
{
    public override void Write(object value)
    {
        WriteLiteral(value);
    }
}

public abstract class TextBasedViewPage<TModel> : System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<TModel>
{
    public override void Write(object value)
    {
        WriteLiteral(value);
    }
}
```

Then in your view you can start out with:

```
@inherits MyNamespace.TextBasedViewPage<MyModelNamespace.Model>
```